# For loop does not doing my async task completely

Tags: java, android

Im doing Download All of files. What I did was for loop, unfortunately my for loop does not finish my async task it continues doing all the loop regardless if it finished the first file that was downloading. Help please.

Here is my for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
            Element e = (Element)nodes.item(i);
            id[i] = ""+CategoriesXMLfunctions.getValue(e, "id");
            name[i] = ""+CategoriesXMLfunctions.getValue(e, "name");
            image[i] = ""+CategoriesXMLfunctions.getValue(e, "image");
            simage[i] = ""+CategoriesXMLfunctions.getValue(e, "simage");
            download[i] = ""+CategoriesXMLfunctions.getValue(e, "download");
            author[i] = ""+CategoriesXMLfunctions.getValue(e, "author");
            genre[i] = ""+CategoriesXMLfunctions.getValue(e, "genre");
            size[i] = ""+CategoriesXMLfunctions.getValue(e, "size");
            price[i] = ""+CategoriesXMLfunctions.getValue(e, "price");
            mylist.add(map);    


        id_all = id[i];
        image_all = image[i];
        dload_all = download[i];
        size_all = size[i];
        name_all = name[i];
        String response = null;
        String resstring = null;
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("devid", "devid"));
        String devid=null;

        try {
                devid =  URLEncoder.encode(Global.getMac(), "UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        try {
            String nURL = "http://....url";
            response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost(nURL, postParameters);
            resstring=response.toString();


            String credit = resstring;
            String priiice = price[i];


            float money = Float.parseFloat(credit);
            float pri = Float.parseFloat(priiice);

            if(pri>money){
               final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainStore.this);
                alert.setMessage("Credits not enough.");
                alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }

                });

                alert.show();
            }else{

                File sd = getDir("xml",MODE_PRIVATE);

                  File todel = new File(sd,id[i]+".xml");
                    todel.delete();
                   String filecreat= "/"+id[i]+".xml";
                   File newfil = new File(sd+ filecreat);
                       if(newfil.exists()){
                        todel.delete();
                       }
                   try{
                   if(!newfil.exists()){
                    newfil.createNewFile();
                }}catch(IOException e1){

                   }



                try{
                     FileWriter fileWritter = new FileWriter(newfil);
                                BufferedWriter bufferWritter = new BufferedWriter(fileWritter);
                                bufferWritter.write("<xml>");
                                bufferWritter.write("<books>");
                                bufferWritter.write("<id>"+id[i]+"</id>");
                                bufferWritter.write("<name>"+name[i]+"</name>");
                                bufferWritter.write("<download>"+download[i]+"</download>");
                                bufferWritter.write("<size>"+size[i]+"</size>");
                                bufferWritter.write("<author>"+author[i]+"</author>");
                                bufferWritter.write("<genre>"+genre[i]+"</genre>");
                                bufferWritter.write("<new>0</new>");
                                bufferWritter.write("</books>");
                                bufferWritter.write("</xml>");
                                bufferWritter.close();

                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
                        }catch(IOException e1){
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error wrting xml "+e1.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  

                        }   

                        downloadallStarted();
                        downloadallfiles();
                        //checkdownloadall();
                        //downloadallFinished();
            }


        }catch (Exception e1){
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error in downloadall: " +e1.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }



        }
```

And here is my async task

```
private void startDownloadall() {
         String fileURL = dload_all;
         fileURL = fileURL.replace(" ", "%20");
        new DownloadFileAsync1().execute(fileURL);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading...start all", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
class DownloadFileAsync1 extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            //showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {

            try {
                String fileURL = dload_all;
                fileURL = fileURL.replace(" ", "%20");
                URL u = new URL(fileURL);
                HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
                c.setRequestMethod("GET");
                c.setDoOutput(true);
                c.connect();

                String PATH = getDir("ebook", MODE_PRIVATE).toString();
                String ebookfile = "";
                //String filename = id[index];
                String filename = id_all;
                if(fileURL.endsWith("pdf"))
                  ebookfile = filename+".pdf";

                else
                  ebookfile = filename+".epub";  
                bookfile = ebookfile;
                Global.setBookfile(bookfile);
                File file = new File(PATH);
                file.mkdirs();
                File outputFile = new File(file, ebookfile);
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

                lenghtOfFilee = c.getContentLength();


                InputStream in = c.getInputStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int len1 = 0;
                long total = 0;

                while ((len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    total += len1; //total = total + len1
                    //publishProgress("" + (int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFilee));
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
                }
                fos.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
               // Log.d("Downloader", e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;

        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
            // Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC",progress[0]);
             //mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
            Global.setBookfile(bookfile);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading..."+lenghtOfFilee, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            checkdownloadall();
            //dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
        }

    }
```

Comment: this may help you [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052153/why-only-1-of-10-image-is-load-and-saved-in-sd-card]

Answer (score 0):

An asynchronous task runs on a background thread, so you directly access variable dload_all in function doInBackground() that is not thread safe. Maybe you can try:

```
private void startDownloadall() {
     //String fileURL = dload_all;
     //fileURL = fileURL.replace(" ", "%20");
    new DownloadFileAsync1().execute(dload_all, id_all);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading...start all", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
class DownloadFileAsync1 extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {

        try {
            String fileURL = args[0];
            fileURL = fileURL.replace(" ", "%20");
            URL u = new URL(fileURL);
            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setDoOutput(true);
            c.connect();

            String PATH = getDir("ebook", MODE_PRIVATE).toString();
            String ebookfile = "";
            //String filename = id[index];
            String filename = args[1];
            if(fileURL.endsWith("pdf"))
              ebookfile = filename+".pdf";

            else
              ebookfile = filename+".epub";  
            bookfile = ebookfile;
            Global.setBookfile(bookfile);
            File file = new File(PATH);
            file.mkdirs();
            File outputFile = new File(file, ebookfile);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

            lenghtOfFilee = c.getContentLength();


            InputStream in = c.getInputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len1 = 0;
            long total = 0;

            while ((len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                total += len1; //total = total + len1
                //publishProgress("" + (int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFilee));
                fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
            }
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
           // Log.d("Downloader", e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;

    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        // Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC",progress[0]);
         //mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
        Global.setBookfile(bookfile);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading..."+lenghtOfFilee, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        checkdownloadall();
        //dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
    }

}
```

Comment: it did not work :( note that, my async task is called inside 'downloadallfiles()' function